# invalid 'in' operand profile in worklight.js

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have two Worklight apps an one SQL-adapter in one project. the first app is the client app and works perfectly well. the second one is the the managment app which is using the same SQL-Adapter. they also call the same procedure, which makes a SQL-statement and returns the results. But when initializing the procedure from the controller app I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand profile worklight.js:4039
```

Adapter-Procedure:

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select TITLE, BODY, DATE from MESSAGES where DATE>?");

function getMessages(param1) {
   return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
     preparedStatement : selectStatement,
     parameters : [param1]
   });
}
```

Call from the Controller:

```
function getMessages(){
    console.log("lala");
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'ClientAdapter',
            procedure : 'getMessages',
            parameters: ['2014-07-21 00:00:00.000000']
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : success,
        onFailure : failure
    });

    function success(result){
        console.log("Successfully gathered Messages");
    }
    function failure(ErrorObject){
        console.log("ERROR: could not get Messages/n" + ErrorObject);
    }
}
```

I don't get how there can be an error there because i never touch that file (to be honest: I don't even know where it's located in my Project)  and in the web inspector it looks the same in both apps.
The only difference is that I'm using Bootstrap in the contorller app instead of jquery mobile.

Any ideas how to fix it or work around?

Sincerely
Max

EDIT: Added code

Comment: Could you add in your sql adapter call? Also, are you using the IN keyword in your query?

Comment: What version of Worklight? What version of Bootstrap? Are you including jQuery with Bootstrap? If yes, what version?

Comment: please show the code that works too, I'm interested especially in the parameter you pass, my suspicion is that the date format may be significant. The fact the the error is being reported in worklight.js is not significant, doesn't imply that that's actually defective, it's just where the error in the request is being discovered.